# Keep a running unique work instead of starting new one

Tags: android, android-workmanager

In the case of a unique work that is in running state, I would like it to be kept instead of starting another unique work.

I thought that `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` would fulfil that for me, but it seems that if there is already a unique work that is in running state and not pending, it will start another work of that unique tag.

From the docs of `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP`:

> If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique
>   name, do nothing.

We do understand that it will keep works only if they are in pending state, but not in running state.

I'm using the latest available version of AndroidX `WorkManager` that was released very lately:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.1.0-rc01

Edit:
I have submitted an issue to the Google team, you can follow up here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137210601

Edit2: Example of scheduling a unique work:

```
    val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker::class.java).build()
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniqueWork("my_worker", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest)
```

EDIT 3: 
After some more tests, it seems that I went wrong claiming that another worker starts while the previous one is running. The mistake came up because the previous worker got into `ENQUEUED` state after it was `RUNNING` because it got interrupted and then was running again from the begining.

To sum it up, `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` works just as intended and makes sure that only one unique work is running.

Comment: Please provide minimal context to your question. the _least_ you can do is say you're using Android WorkManager (and provide the version). Adding this in your tags is not enough

Comment: @Zun This is pretty much of a general question in `WorkManager` so there shouldn't be any specific context. Also, I'm not sure how the version is a relevant piece of information.

Comment: Providing a version number is important because Google has recently pushed out plenty of betas/RC/alphas. Your issue might be fixed in another update. Keyword here being "might".

Comment: @Zun I've added the version in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` means that, If there's already a `WorkRequest` with the same `uniqueWorkName` in a **NON FINISHED** state, WorkManager will simply ignore the new request and **KEEP** the previous one.

What does it means **FINISHED**?
As indicated in the [`isFinished()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State#isFinished()) function, a `WorkRequest` is finished when it is in one of the following state: `SUCCEEDED`, `FAILED`, and  `CANCELLED`.

There's some state diagram available in this presentation:
[Embracing WorkManager](https://speakerdeck.com/nibble/embrace-workmanager?slide=45)

This is the one for OneTimeWorker
[image]

This is the one for PeriodicWorker
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think it is worth to update the docs. Instead of claiming if "existing pending state" do nothing, it should be noted as if "non-finished" do nothing, which is more right.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your work has finished before scheduling a new one if the `KEEP` policy only applies to the pending Jobs.

```
WorkManager.getInstance()
  .getStatusById(request.id)
  .observe(this@MainActivity, Observer {
    it?.let {
        val workerResult = it.outputData     
        if (it.state.isFinished) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Work completed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
           .show()
           //Schedule the job again
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Work not completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
           .show()
           //Do Nothing
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hoped that their API will do better supporting this, as it is going to get ugly when having multiple types of unique workers.

Comment: Also you say that the enqueueUniqueWork will start another Work if the previous one is running, but does it execute? O it waits until the first one finishes? The docs says it shoudn't https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)

Comment: It executes while the previous one is running. The docs are correct, it states that it would start only if the previous one is pending.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are configuring, initializing and scheduling the Jobs?

Comment: Yes, I've provided in the original post.

Comment: Please see my last edit, it seems that `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` works just fine.